# Cart in Magento CE1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cart

After customer login Some times I get same and some times get different id's from these two lines why?(I know one is for admin side and one is for frontend but it should sync)

- `$id1 = $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadbycustomer($session- >getId())->getId();`
- `$id1 = $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getId();`

and if use any of line to add product to cart always I get `price and subtotal of products null` do not know why?

But If I use `'checkout/cart'` in that case price and subtotal show. But I can not use that for logged in users.